# How to change the default time format in django models

Tags: django, datetime, django-models

I have a `DateTimeField` with `auto_now_add=True` and everything work except when i try to use that date in a template i get a date which is in the format of   'June 23, 2018, 4:33 p.m.' but the date that I need should be formatted like this DD-MM-YY / hh:mm.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `date` filter in the template for this. For example, for your answer:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p>{{pub_date|date:"d-m-y / H:i"}}</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the complete list of formatting characters: [Django, Built in Template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date)